# Scrape file to be immediately available in python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, flush, fsync

I am using beautifulsoup to scrape .csv files from a selection of websites. I then would like to use them immediately in the same script and store them for later use. Currently, when I scrape and save the file it is not immediately available to the script, and is returning a `NoneType` error when attempting to load the csv as a dataframe. 
I have attempted to use

`file_to_save.flush()`

and

`os.fsync(file_to_save.fileno())`

to no avail. I have also tried not using the buffer when opening the file `file_to_save = open(path + filename, 'wb', 0)`, and this still is not working.

My code is below (`res` is the `response.read()` of the request):

```
file_to_save = open(path + filename, 'wb', 0)
file_to_save.write(res)
file_to_save.flush()
os.fsync(file_to_save.fileno())
file_to_save.close()
```

When I re-run the script, it works as the file is saved and can be loaded into the df in a separate function. Any ideas as to how I can make the file immediately available?

Comment: Can you read the file into pandas after calling `close`?

Comment: How are you loading the file? Are you attempting to read from the file you just wrote without seeking back to the beginning first?

Comment: @KenSyme I can only read the file if the whole process ends and restarts - if I try to read the file in a separate function later in the script it raises a `NoneType` error as it cannot load the file. If I run the script again, it works as the file is saved and outputted.

Comment: @DanD. I am attempting to load the file as a pandas dataframe using pd.read_csv(file_path) after it has been saved and closed. I am not sure what you mean by 'seeking back to the beginning'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a satisfactory solution to this, the above suggestions all failed.

The way I solved this problem was by opening the scraped file as a pandas dataframe and returning this dataframe through the functions to be used elsewhere in the webapp. The file was still saved and available for the next use.